# ListView in Fragment not refreshing

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, refresh

I have a custom ListView inside a fragment that represents a list of activities. Each activity is saved in a database (I'm using [Parse](http://www.parse.com/)), and the ListView is populated with the Activities from the database. There is an add button in the fragment that takes the user to an screen where he/she can create a new Activity object. When the user is done, the activity is finished (I call `finish()` on the Activity), and the fragment is brought back up. The problem is that the ListView doesn't refresh- it's the same list before the user was sent to the Activity Create screen.

I tried to override the `onStart` and `onResume` in my fragment class and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `invalidateViews()` but neither method works, the list view doesn't refresh so it includes the new Activity that was just created  by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Start the activity that adds Activity with `startActivityForResult()`. Override the `onActivityResult()` in your listview fragment to get notified when the user has finished adding an Activity. Then, refresh your `ListView` by querying the database again or adding the new Activity to the adapter (depending on how you implemented the listview adapter).

Answer (score 0):

In your case it looks like you forget to **refill the activity list** attached to adapter from which listview generate views.
Refill the list again from scratch and then call `notifyDataSetChanged();`. Your listview will be updated with new entries.

Cheers